# create scoring function and apply to each row in R

Tags: r

I'd like to apply a function to each row in R that "scores" each value of a row, x. It seems like i'd use the 'apply' function in R to do this, but not sure how to do it. I'd like to input a dataframe with a column of values of integers and have a vector output with the score. The code I have now is as follows:

```
ScoreFn <- function(x){
  score <- 0
  if(x<1) {
    score <- 0
  } else if(x==1) {
    score <- 5
  } else if(x==2) {
    score <- 10
  } else if(x==3) {
    score <- 20
  } else if(x >= 4 && x <= 10) {
    score <- 30
  } else if(x >= 11 && x <= 20) {
    score <- 40
  } else if(x >= 21) {
    score <- 50
  }

  return(score)
}

apply(df$x, 1, ScoreFn())
```

Also, I am getting this message. Not sure the best way to do this function.

```
1: In if (x < 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (x == 2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (x == 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is just a column of data.frame, you don't need to use `apply`. You can use `sapply` instead.

```
ScoreFn <- function(x){
 score <- 0
  if(x<1) {
    score <- 0
  } else if(x==1) {
    score <- 5
  } else if(x==2) {
    score <- 10
  } else if(x==3) {
    score <- 20
  } else if(x >= 4 && x <= 10) {
    score <- 30
  } else if(x >= 11 && x <= 20) {
    score <- 40
  } else if(x >= 21) {
    score <- 50
  }

  return(score)
}

# Return a list of scores
sapply(df$x, ScoreFn)
```

Comment: Nevermind--sapply worked well. I guess my errors above were just warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can make a vectorised function, using cut, so you don't have to use apply at all:

```
scorefun <- function(x){
   as.numeric(as.character(cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 21, Inf),
                                  labels = c(0,5,10,20,30,40, 50), right = FALSE)))
}
df <- data.frame(x = 0:10)
scorefun(df$x)
[1]  0  5 10 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
```

This also has the bonus that cut does the heavy lifting of typing the if/elses, as well as being about 10x faster than the non-vectorised version.

It works by cutting the given vector (in this case `df$x`) into factors by slices, given by breaks. We then label them with your scores, and then get out the numbers again by using `as.character` and `as.numeric`.